# Google custom search result have only results from google map

Tags: android, google-custom-search

I have recently implemented Google Custom search. I am getting a result but it every link in it whether it is for website or image or thumbnail, it is from maps.

example result -

```
 {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",

   "title": "Saga Tree",

   "htmlTitle": "Saga \u003cb\u003eTree\u003c/b\u003e",

   "link": "https://***www.google.com/mymaps***/viewer?mid=1yF1gMCZhBaeEouT9GB-7bQqXmuw&hl=en",

   "formattedUrl": "***https://www.google.com/mymaps***/viewer?mid...7bQqXmuw&hl...",

   "pagemap": {

      "cse_thumbnail": [
         {
          "width": "221",
          "height": "228",

          "src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2SZoZ2AF7PUVw5wGucLb5Hd4k1Bwkt3x6__ed8E_01Mlq5Fwd7nKpKI2b"
         }
    ],
    "website": [
         {
          "name": "Saga Tree",
          "description": "Saga Tree",
          "url": "***https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer***?mid=1yF1gMCZhBaeEouT9GB-7bQqXmuw&hl=en",

          "image": "***https://www.google.com/maps***/d/thumbnail?mid=1yF1gMCZhBaeEouT9GB-7bQqXmuw&hl=en"

         }
    ],
    "metatags": [
         {
          "viewport": "initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0,width=device-width",
          "og:type": "website",
          "og:title": "Saga Tree",
          "og:description": "Saga Tree",
          "og:url": "***https://www.google.com/maps***/d/viewer?mid=1yF1gMCZhBaeEouT9GB-7bQqXmuw&hl=en",

          "og:image": "***https://www.google.com/maps***/d/thumbnail?mid=1yF1gMCZhBaeEouT9GB-7bQqXmuw&hl=en",

          "twitter:card": "summary_large_image",
          "twitter:title": "Saga Tree",
          "twitter:description": "Saga Tree",

          "twitter:image:src": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1yF1gMCZhBaeEouT9GB-7bQqXmuw&hl=en"

         }
    ],
    "cse_image": [
         {

          "src": "https://www.google.com/maps/d/thumbnail?mid=1yF1gMCZhBaeEouT9GB-7bQqXmuw&hl=en"

         }
    ]
   }
 }
```

This is with every result. I want results as if I have searched it in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when the Custom Search API performs search only with the default included site ( www.google.com ). This is the default. To change it go to **Basics -> Sites to Search** under your Custom Search engine and choose "**Search the entire web but emphasise included sites**" instead of the default "Search only included sites".

Also ensure **Image Search** is enabled under Basics.

[image]